# Capacitor DAC - Charge Redistribution

Tags: adc, data

I was reading about capacitor based DACs for a SAR ADC in an Analog Devices pdf(https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-021.pdf) and I saw this
[image]

[image]

**About the highlighted part, I understand charge redistribution takes place, but how do we know that it will be exactly Vref/2 added on?**

Comment: Strange. I think it should be adding VREF not VREF/2?

Comment: There is C/2 + C/4 + C/4 = C on the A node via S2, S3, S4 so when S1 goes from ground to Vref. the voltage divides by 2 to give VREF/2.

Comment: Ah yes missed the part that said the others are connected to ground.

Comment: @KevinWhite I understand it's a capacitive divider and that's where you're getting the /2 from. But the parallel combination of C/2, C/4 and C/4 (= C) has a voltage -Ain across it. When S1 goes from ground to Vref, shouldn't the amount of charge that get's redistributed depend on the voltage difference between -Ain and Vref? Once the charge redistributes and the new voltage settles on both capacitors, then only we would have a final voltage? How can you assume the Vref is going to divide by 2? Isn't the charge and hence voltage going to be dependant on how much higher Vref is above -Ain?

Comment: Okay, so when S1 goes to Vref from ground and C1 MSB get's charged to -Ain+Vref. There is now a voltage difference between C1 and the other parallel capacitors (grouped together wth value C). Charge redistirbuton takes place and current flows from C1(MSB) to the other parallel capacitors until the voltage across all capacitor settles at -Ain+Vref/2. Now, just to confirm, if the parallel capacitors added up to 5C instead of C, then we would have -Ain+Vref/10 correct? - since V=Q/C