# Capacitor Charge Redistribution

Tags: capacitor

Consider the following situation

[image]

We have two capacitors, C<sub>1</sub> and C<sub>2</sub>, both with a value of 10μF. The capacitor C<sub>1</sub> through some switching action now has a voltage of -A<sub>in</sub> + V<sub>ref</sub> across it whereas C<sub>2</sub> has just -A<sub>in</sub> across it.

My understanding is that, current will flow from C<sub>1</sub> to C<sub>2</sub>, redistributing the charges and the circuit will settle to a steady-state in which both capacitors have a voltage of -A<sub>in</sub> + V<sub>ref</sub>/2 across them as shown below:

[image]

My question is, **what would happen if C<sub>1</sub> had a value of 10μF but C<sub>2</sub> had a value of 50μF?** I understand that V = Q/C, so in order to equalise the voltage, it would take a lot more charge on the plates of C<sub>2</sub>. With the conservation of charge in mind, does that mean the final voltage across both capacitors would be -A<sub>in</sub> +V<sub>ref</sub>/10?
In that case, we are missing (8/10)*V<sub>ref</sub> - where did that voltage go?

Comment: The "voltage" doesn't "go anywhere". On a charged capacitor a certain voltage means a certain charge. If you change the capacitor value (C) while the charge Q remains the same, then V will change. Maybe related: the two capacitor paradox: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie So, what would the final voltage be?

Comment: So basically, charge is still conserved always, so in this case, the final voltage across both capacitors would be -Ain +Vref/10. The missing 8/10*Vref is due to ideal circuit theory failing?

Answer (score 1):

Your first circuit is **invalid** and can not be analyzed by the usual means. You have two ideal capacitors in **parallel**, which means that the voltage across them **must** be the same. However, you specify that they have different voltages. This is not possible if you are talking about ideal wires and ideal capacitors.

To make the circuit analyzable you must add a resistance between the capacitors. Then you need to analyze the current flow and determine how much energy is lost in the resistor before you can see the final states of the capacitors.

For a more detailed discussion, see [Capacitor Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two_capacitor_paradox)

Comment: That's the equivalent circuit from a SAR DAC. see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/460100/capacitor-dac-charge-redistribution?noredirect=1#comment1158057_460100

Comment: No, I think the situation in the linked question is different. In that question it looks like the capacitors in parallel are connected to a voltage source and that they all have the same voltage, or they are all disconnected from any voltage source but all have the same voltage.

Comment: Initially yes, but then the MSB capacitor is charged to -Ain + Vref as the switch S1 changes to Vref from ground and thus now the MSB capacitor has a voltage of -Ain + Vref across it, yet all the other capacitors still only have -Ain, hence leading us to the problem I have shown here.

Comment: @AlfroJang80, that is the simplified equivalent model of a SAR DAC, in particular it ignore the resistance (and inductance) that is always present in real electronics because for the purpose of demonstrating what they wished to show, it didn't matter.  The (introductory) circuit theory notion of a wire as being something of zero resistance, zero inductance and having zero capacitance to other wires (or even to other points on itself) is a nice simplification that more or less works for many teaching problems (because they are designed that way), but it gets you into trouble in the limits.

Comment: Don't get wrapped around the axle with the "two capacitor paradox." There's no paradox and it doesn't help with your question anyhow. It's really just a puzzle.

Comment: There's a two spring "paradox" just like the tow capacitor one. The answer to where the energy went is "into the resistor" for two capacitors, and "into the dashpot" for two springs.

Comment: @john But there is no resistor in the OP's schematic! Without a resistor you have a fundamental problem.

Comment: @Eliot Alderson There's also no dashpot in the two spring variation. What you actually would have, if such a thing were possible, is a zero ohm resistor with an infinite current flowing through it for zero seconds. It can be shown, using L'Hopital's Rule, that the "lost" energy is dissipated in the zero ohm resistor.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson  can we say that lumped model is not valid because we cannot ignore the effect of fringing field which causes induction effect while energy calculation ignores these effects , and to remove induction effect we have to separate both capacitor to infinite distance  but it causes failure of another condition of lumped model that is size of circuit is much larger than wavelength of electromagnetic wave?

Answer (score 0):

Since you know V=Q/C, you know voltage is inversely proportional to C.  Whatever difference there is in the two voltages C1-C2 will then be multiplied by C1/(C1+C2) or 1/6 in your second example.

Comment: Ah yes! So steady-state voltage at the end will be -Ain + (1/6)Vref

Answer (score 0):

> The capacitor C1 through some switching action now has a voltage of -Ain + Vref across it whereas C2 has just -Ain across it.

To make the "switching action" apparent, let's redraw your schematic to show a switch

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUHrk7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In each capacitor, the voltage, charge and capacitance are related by

$$C_nV_n = Q_n$$

Where \$V_n\$ is the voltage across capacitor \$C_n\$ and \$Q_n\$ is that capacitor's charge.

When the switch is closed, the voltages must become equal, but the total charge must be conserved. We will use primes to indicate values after the switch is closed, and the absence of primes to indicate values before the switch is closed.

So.

$$C_1V_1 = Q_1$$
$$C_2V_2 = Q_2$$

$$Q_{total} = Q_1 + Q_2 = Q'_1 + Q'_2$$
$$V' = V'_1 = V'_2 = C_1Q'_1 = C_2Q'_2$$

with a bit of re-arranging.

$$Q_{total} = V_1C_1 + V_2C_2 = V'C_1 + V'C_2 = V'(C_1 + C_2)$$

$$V' = \frac{V_1C_1 + V_2C_2}{C_1 + C_2}$$

> My understanding is that, current will flow from C1 to C2, redistributing the charges and the circuit will settle to a steady-state in which both capacitors have a voltage of -Ain + Vref/2 across them

If \$C_1 = C_2\$, yes.

> *what would happen if C1 had a value of 10μF but C2 had a value of 50μF?*

Then the final voltage will be

$$V' = \frac{10V_1 + 50V_2}{10 + 50} = \frac{V_1 + 5V_2}{6} = \frac{-A_{in} + V_{ref} -5A_{in}}{6} = \frac{-6A_{in} + V_{ref}}{6} = -A_{in} + \frac{1}{6}V_{ref}$$

So, the answer is \$-A_{in} + \frac{1}{6}V_{ref}\$ not \$-A_{in} + \frac{1}{10}V_{ref}\$